# How to increase cell values and stop it when it's greater than a limit in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am designing a script for a Google Sheet where I can control limit values of a cell, based on the adjoining cell as shown below:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

First click on `+` (which is a drawing "button"):

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Click on `+`:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Click on `+`:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Click on `+`:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Click on `+`:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Week 1 (until 11/4) | Week 2 (until 18/4) | Week 3 (until 25/4) | Week 4 (until 2/5) | Week 5 (until 9/5) | Week 6 (until 16/5) |
| 2 | John + | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

and so on.

I have the following script where `onPress` is assigned to the `+` drawing:

```
var limitPerWeek = 2;

function onPress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var weeks = [
    sheet.getRange('B2'),
    sheet.getRange('C2'),
    sheet.getRange('D2'),
    sheet.getRange('E2'),
    sheet.getRange('F2'),
    sheet.getRange('G2')
  ];
  var totalWeeks = weeks.length;

  weeks[0].setValue(weeks[0].getValue() + 1);
  for (var i=0; i<totalWeeks-1; i++) {
    if (checkLimit(weeks[i])) {
      weeks[i+1].setValue(weeks[i+1].getValue() + 1);
    }
  }
  checkLimit(weeks[totalWeeks-1]);
}

function checkLimit(week) {
  if (week.getValue() > limitPerWeek) {
    week.setValue(limitPerWeek);
    return true;
  }
}
```

The code works fine. However, when I add a lot of columns, the wait time becomes very long, and the code ends up being inefficient.

**How could the efficiency of the script be improved and how could weeks be stored in a more elegant way?**

### Code so far

This is the code I get thanks to [Lle.4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977821/11617040):

```
var limitPerWeek = 2;

function onPress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:G2");
  var vals = range.getValues()[0];
  var totalWeeks = vals.length;

  vals[0]++;
  for (var i=0; i<totalWeeks-1; i++) {
    if (checkLimit(vals[i])) {
      vals[i+1]++;
    }
  }
  checkLimit(vals[totalWeeks-1]);

  console.log(vals);

  range.setValues([vals]);
}

function checkLimit(week) {
  if (week > limitPerWeek) {
    week = limitPerWeek;
    return true;
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it increments all the values at the same time. I have put `console.log` in a lot of places but I don't realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will loop through the values in C2:G2 until it finds one that's less than limitPerWeek.

It will then increment that value by 1 and place the new set of values back in B2:G2.

If all the values in B2:G2 equal limitPerWeek then the code will exit without doing anything, not sure what, if anything you would want it do in that case.

```javascript
var limitPerWeek = 2;

function onPress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var weeks = sheet.getRange('B2:G2').getValues();
  
  let i = 0;

  console.log(i);

  while (weeks[0][i]>=limitPerWeek || i > weeks[0].length) {
    i=i+1;
  }

  if (i<weeks[0].length){
    weeks[0][i] = weeks[0][i]+1;

    sheet.getRange('B2:G2').setValues(weeks);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to include column `B`, why is excluded? Is the code efficient with a large number of columns (weeks) and a `limitPerWeek` equal to `20-40`?

Comment: That's a typo - I'll fix it , in the code B2:G2 is being used. Not sure about efficiency, shouldn't be too bad as all the code does is change one value.

Comment: The code is still excluding column `B` (Week 1) from being incremented.

Comment: Should we just change `let i = 0;` to `let i = -1;` to include Column B?

Comment: When I run the code B is being incremented and you shouldn't need to change anything - the code had the correct range, it was in my explanation that the range was incorrect.

Comment: Sorry but the code increments starting from C, not B, as shown here: https://imgur.com/tFr6hG9 If I change to `let i = -1;`, B is included. Why this happens??

Comment: What happens it you clear all the values from B2:G2? P.S. If you make that change it'll cause an error.

Comment: It is weird. If I change the code to `let i=-1;`, the code works fine. Perhaps it happens because "Enable Chrome V8 runtime" is checked by default?

Comment: My bad, changing it to let i=-1 will work.

Comment: Right, I was using the wrong type of loop - I've changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I am curious why some sentences cannot have `;` at the send, such as `i=i+1`.

Comment: That's a typo, strictly there should be a ;.

Answer (score 1):

I think your primary issue is that you use `sheet.getRange()` and `Range.setValue()` over and over again, which can take a lot of time at scale. Could you instead use `sheet.getRange()` one time on a larger range (e.g. for your example, `var range = sheet.getRange("B2:G2")`), and then use `var vals = range.getValues()[0]` to get the array of values? Then, instead of setting the value each time, you could do the validations within the array itself, modify `vals`, and then use `range.setValues([vals])` to set that original array, now modified in only one column, to the updated values. Does that help the runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have added the code with your comments, but I couldn't get it to work. Can you check it?

Comment: Sure thing! You just need to add a line decrementing `vals[i]` when you increment `vals[i+1]`. So, on line 14, right after `vals[i+1]++;`, just write a new line that says `vals[i]--;`. Does that fix it? @manooooh

Comment: One other thing to watch with this solution is that the final value can increase without bound. You could write another if statement to catch that if you wanted to.